# datagridview formatting not applying

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my form load event I am setting the defaultcellstyle formats. They are not taking hold anyone know why? None of the formatting that is expected in the code after I bind the datatable to the grid is getting done even though the code steps through it

```
Private Sub frmADRORD_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'wire the delegate function for incoming updates
    AddHandler m_helper.DataUpdate, AddressOf UpdateGridInvoker
    'bind the visual grid with the binding source
    Me.datagridADRORD.DataSource = dsGridView

    'get data from helper class
    m_dt = m_helper.GetTable()

    'bind the binding source with datatable
    Me.datagridADRORD.DataSource = m_dt

    **'after data loaded, auto resize columns and format
    Me.datagridADRORD.AutoResizeColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
    With Me.datagridADRORD.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
        .BackColor = Color.Gold
        .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        .Font = New Font(Control.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With
    Me.datagridADRORD.Columns("ADR Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##.##"
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.datagridADRORD.Rows
        row.Cells("ORD Price").DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(m_helper.CurrCultureInfoStr(row.Cells("Currency").Value))
    Next
    Me.datagridADRORD.Columns("Currency Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##.####"
    Me.datagridADRORD.Columns("Difference").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##.##"**
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `ValueType` of the column, and "##.##" doesn't seem to work (in C# anyway).

This works in C#:

```
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].ValueType = typeof(Double);
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Also the data being bound has to actually be of some numeric type (I presume it is, but can't be sure from your code snippet).

You'll have to translate `typeof()` to equivalent VB.NET, and I don't know whether the difference between "##.##" and "N2" is a control thing (in which case you'll need to change it) or a language thing (in which case you won't).